# Eclipse RCP - Use Classes from a library that are imported from another plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

follow situation.

-pluiginCore  <- includes many Libraries (libA,liB) via pom.xml, do nothing else

-pluginA..F <- want use classes from libA.
-pluginF..Z <- want use classes from libB.

Is this possible with RCP? 
Is this a good way?
Do I need to import via pom.xml libA and LibB in each plugin where I wanna use it?

I added pluginCore as a dependency of pluginA but still cant use libA.

Comment: Plugins can only use libraries that are included in plugins, they can't reference external jars.

Comment: Yes, this is what I try to achieve. For that reason i added libA and libB to pluginCore. After that I add a dependecy to from pluginA to Core in hope that i can use libA.

Comment: You don't use maven dependencies for this. It must be done with the MANIFEST.MF directives for this - Bundle-ClassPath, Export-Package, Require-Bundle, Import-Package. The MANIFEST.MF is the only thing the Eclipse plugin system looks at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this using the directives in the MANIFEST.MF of the plugins.

For the plugin which contains the libraries you use the `Bundle-ClassPath` to specifies the jars in the plugin. For example:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,
 lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,
 lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

The `.` entry is for the normal code in the plugin, the other entries are jars in a `lib` directory.

You must also specify the additional jars in the `build.properties` for the plugin.

You use the `Export-Package` directive to say which packages from these jars are available to other plugins:

```
Export-Package: com.jcraft.jogg,
 com.jcraft.jorbis
```

Plugins which wish to refer to these packages can either use `Require-Bundle` to add a dependency to the plugin exporting the packages, or they can use `Import-Package` to let Eclipse find the imported package.

Comment: One other thing - if you are using maven look at [Eclipse Tycho](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) which provides support for building RCPs and plugins to maven.